# Как вывести время создания куки?

Tags: php, cookie

Как вывести время создания куки ? **Разобрался**

```
$Visit = '';
if(isset($_COOKIE['Visit'])){
    $Visit = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $_COOKIE['Visit']);
    setcookie('Visit', time(), time()+3600, '/');
}
```

Comment: Сначала разберитесь откуда вы будете брать время создания. Для куки задается только время уничтожения

Answer (score 4):

Никак.

Если Вам нужно время создания куки, то нужно самому это время создания сохранить либо в отдельной переменной, либо в каком-нибудь поле внутри куки (если сохраняете объект или массив).

Т.е. для массива в Вашем случае можно сделать что-то вроде:

```
$password = !empty($_COOKIE['password']) ? json_decode($_COOKIE['password']) : array();

if(!empty($password['date_created'])){
    echo "Время создания " . $password['date_created'];
}
```

При этом сохранялось значение как-то так:

```
setcookie('password', json_encode(array('value' => '', 'date_created' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))));
```